Processing two AD names when executing "Get-ADUser -Identity"
I'm new to Povershell. I am creating a script to obtain data about an AD user from Winform. I selected the user by name because it’s more convenient. But the Active Directory contains the same names and the script throws an error. How to handle this situation?


$Users = Get-ADuser -filter * -Properties Name
Foreach ($User in $Users)
{
$ComboBox1.Items.Add($User.Name)
}
function Button1_Click()
{
$script:user1 = $ComboBox1.SelectedItem
$script:selected_user = (get-aduser -ldapfilter "(displayname=$user1)" -property samaccountname | select-object -property samaccountname).samaccountname 
write-host $selected_user
if ((Get-ADUser -Identity $selected_user).Enabled)
{
 $Label6.Text = ''
 $Label6.Forecolor = 'Green'
 $Label6.Text = 'User enabled'
}
else
{
 $Label6.Text = '' 
 $Label6.Forecolor = 'Red'
 $Label6.Text = 'User disabled'
}
}


Identity is usually the samaccountname.

You can try get-aduser -filter 'anr -eq "firstname lastname"'

What do you want to happen if the user could not be found?

Or multiple users returned...

The issue with your code is the second call to Get-ADUser, it is not needed and can be removed. If you wanted to handle that error you can use a try / catch statement but again, not really needed in this case.
You're already querying for the user using LDAPFilter which already will not produce any errors unless $user1 was null or empty, so you can simply remove the expansion of .SamAccountName there and use the object as is:
function Button1_Click() {
    $script:user1 = $ComboBox1.SelectedItem
    $script:selected_user = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(displayname=$user1)"
    Write-Host $selected_user
    if (-not $selected_user) {
        # here is for user couldn't be found with that displayName
    }
    elseif ($selected_user.Enabled) {
        $Label6.Text = ''
        $Label6.Forecolor = 'Green'
        $Label6.Text = 'User enabled'
    }
    else {
        $Label6.Text = ''
        $Label6.Forecolor = 'Red'
        $Label6.Text = 'User disabled'
    }
}


Handling duplicate names.
$user1 = 'Frodo Baggins' 
$Users = (get-aduser -ldapfilter "(displayname=$user1)" -property samaccountname).samaccountname
if ($Users.Count -gt 1)
{
   $User1 = ($Users | select -First 1)
   write-host "First account: $User1"

   $User2 = ($Users | select -Last 1)
   write-host "Second account: $User2"
}
else 
{
   write-host $Users
}


You don't need to specify -property SamAccountName, because that is returned in the default property sey from Get-ADUser. What is you get more than two users returned? You need a loop there.
